# How can I pass a variable from a service to a library, in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been developing an e-commerce app with Angular 14.

I am currently working on a *product search* feature.

```
export class ProductListComponent extends ComponentWithLoading implements OnInit {

    public searchCriteria: string;
    public searchText: string;
    
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private productService: ProductService
      ) {
        super();
    }
      
      
    public searchProducts(
        page?: number,
        pageSize?: number,
        searchCriteria?: string,
        searchText?: string
      ): void {
        this.showLoading();
        this.productService.setSearchParams(this.searchCriteria, this.searchText);
        this.productService
          .searchProducts(page, pageSize, searchCriteria, searchText)
          .pipe(
            take(1),
            tap((response: ApiPagination<ProductBase[]>) => {
              this.products = response.content ?? [];
              this.pageSettings = response.page;
            }),
            delay(250),
            finalize(() => this.hideLoading())
          )
          .subscribe();
      } 
}

<div class="product-search">
  <mat-form-field class="search-box">
    <input matInput placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="searchText">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Search by" [(ngModel)]="searchCriteria">
      <mat-option value="name">Name</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="role">Category</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="country">Country of origin</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="searchProducts(page, pageSize, searchCriteria, searchText)">Search</button>
</div>
```

In the **ProductService** I have:

```
export class ProductService implements BaseService {

  public searchParams: object[];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}


  public setSearchParams(searchCriteria: string, searchText: string) {
    this.searchParams = [{
      searchCriteria: searchCriteria,
      searchText: searchText
    }];
    console.log('Search params from the ProductService', this.searchParams);
  }

  public searchProducts(
      pageNumber?: number,
      size?: number,
      searchCriteria?: string,
      searchText?: string,
      ): Observable<ApiPagination<ProductBase[]>> {
    return this.productRepo.searchProducts(pageNumber, size, searchCriteria, searchText);
  }
  
}
```

The `setSearchParams` method above successfully returns the search parameters from the search-box.

I also use a **pagination library** to paginate the products list(s), whether they result from a search or not. Here is the library:

```
export class Pagination {
  public pageNumber: number;
  public size: number;
  public searchParams: object[];

  constructor(
    pageNumber?: number,
    size?: number,
    searchParams?: object[]
  ) {
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber ?? 0;
    this.size = size ?? 10;
    this.searchParams = [
      {
        searchCriteria: 'name',
        searchText: 'Laptop'
      }
    ];
  }

    public getPaginationParams(): HttpParams {
     let params = new HttpParams();

     if (this.searchParams.length) {
      this.searchParams.forEach(sp => {
        Object.entries(sp).forEach(entry => {
           params = params.append(entry[0], entry[1]);
        });
      });
    }

    params = params.append('page', this.pageNumber);
    params = params.append('size', this.size);

    return params;
  }
}
```

I *use the library* in another service:

```
export class ProductRepository {

    public searchParams: object[];

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private apiService: ApiService) { }

    public searchProducts(
        pageNumber?: number,
        size?: number,
        searchCriteria?: string,
        searchText?: string
      ): Observable<ApiPagination<ProductBase[]>> {
        const url = 'ProductsSearch';
        const params = new Pagination(
          pageNumber,
          size
        ).getPaginationParams();
        console.log(params);

        return this.httpClient
          .get<ApiPagination<ProductBase[]>>(this.apiService.constructUrl(url), {
              params
            }
          )
          .pipe(catchError(() => of()));
    }

}
```

The above class *takes the params from the library* and I understand the necessity. But I need to also pass the `searchParams` object *to* the library.

#### The goal

The goal (necessity) is to make the *Pagination* library take (the values of) it's search params (`searchParams` variable) from the *ProductService* service, instead of the hardcoded "name" and "Laptop".

In other words, I take the search params from `ProductListComponent`, via the UI and the model, and **need to pass it in the pagination library**.

#### The problem

Importing the service in the library not only seems bad software design, but it results in compilation errors.

###### Question

How can I bring the search params from the *ProductService* service to the library?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Konrad The _ProductService_ is responsible with more then the product lists, so I do not want to to import it in the library.

Comment: why not pass to the function `getPaginationParams()` the "searchParams" instead of use the constructor?

Comment: @Eliseo Where? How?

Comment: We don't know where do you use this class

Comment: @Konrad I _use_ the library in the `ProductRepository` class.

Comment: I would use `ProductService` in `ProductRepository` to get the values

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I don't understand how your `Pagination` class is a library. JavaScript libraries are pre-compiled code that comes from a third party. The `Pagination` class looks like any Angular component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question and comments, seems like you really want to pass the data to your library. In that case, I'd just use `sessionStorage` to avoid any circular dependency or compiler error.

- You can also use `localStorage` if you want to keep the data beyond the session for better user experience.

```
public setSearchParams(searchCriteria: string, searchText: string) {
    this.searchParams = [{
      searchCriteria: searchCriteria,
      searchText: searchText
    }];
    console.log('Search params from the ProductService', this.searchParams);
    sessionStorage.setItem('searchParams', JSON.stringify(this.searchParams))
  }
```

In pagination library:

```
this.searchParams = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('searchParams')  as string);
```

Comment: It is a nice solution, but isn't it "external" to Angular and RxJs? :)

Comment: Using Angular doesn't mean LS/SS/cookies are forbidden. They are still at your disposal. It's what you store in them that matters. PII or sensitive data should not be stored in such storage, but harmless data like search params can easily be managed with them.

Comment: In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51536262) I don't see anyone opposing to using LS/SS with Angular.

Comment: Importing the `ProductService` into `ProductRepository` results in a `No provider for ProductService!` error and adding it to the `ProductRepository` results in a `Circular dependency` error.

Comment: Got it! Removed from my answer.

Comment: In the service, `console.log(sessionStorage.setItem('searchParams', JSON.stringify(this.searchParams)))` returns `undefined`.

Comment: That's what it's designed to do. `setItem` doesn't return anything to `console.log`. If you want to check what's stored, use 'getItem', or [check in dev tool of Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170381/what-is-session-storage-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 1):

why you not store your data on an subject like a behaviourSubject, and when u need u subscribe, get the data and unsubscribe

use ur service to create your behaviorSubject and store the data whenever you want, after u only have to subscribe on your service behaviorSubject

on your service do this:

```
    yourSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(<unknow>);
```

on your component that have the data:

```
    paramsSubject$ = yourservice.yourSubject$
paramsSubject$.next("b");
```

And whenever you want the data do this:

```
    paramsSubject$ = yourservice.yourSubject$
paramsSubject$.subscribe(value => {
  console.log("Subscription got", value); 
});
```

i think you can do the same thing as i answered here

[Angular: how to share data from custom-component with app-component (app-root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70024640/angular-how-to-share-data-from-custom-component-with-app-component-app-root/70028739?noredirect=1#comment128850985_70028739)

Comment: Is that a way to pass a variable from a service to a library or an _alternative_ to doing that?

Comment: In terms of solid, there is a code smell related to srp. Why are you storing "searchParams" if you don't use it into the service, besides this on every call basically you are sending all the information which is encapsulated within that searcParams, and based on that you could create anytime that object.

Comment: I am not trying to pass the variable to a component, but to a *library*.

Comment: @ZsoltB I take the search params from ProductListComponent, via the UI and the model, and need to pass it in the pagination library.

Comment: But what is the point with seachCriteria and searcTex setting it within the service? you are already passing those ones in the component by calling  this.productService
.searchProducts(page, pageSize, searchCriteria, searchText). Setting it like this : this.productService.setSearchParams(this.searchCriteria, this.searchText), basically are the same value which you passed at the search call.